# Getting a div wrapped around two widgets

Tags: widgets

To get the layout I'm looking for, I (think that I) need to get a div to surround two of the three widgets that I am placing in a widget area. Is there a way to do this without making a new sort of widget?

For those of you who are fans of XY problems, let me state the underlying layout goal. The overall widget area is to consist of two columns. One column contains widget 1, the other column is to contain widget 2 followed by 3. Simply floating one left and the others right doesn't do what I want if the left content is not taller than 'widget 1'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem of it not doing what you wanted can be solved by not floating any elements and instead relying on flex-box or grid to style the layout. Changing the markup is unnecessary, there are pure CSS solutions to your original problem. There's also separating the widget area in to 2 areas and wrapping it in the theme. Of all the available solutions, the one you asked about is the most difficult to implement as it requires making a new sort of widget and internal knowledge of how widgets work which not many people have

Comment: Ironically, this would be trivial to do with block based widgets or the block editor via a column block, but that would require experimental features of the gutenberg plugin

Comment: Maybe you can use 2 HTML widgets, one on the first position with a div start tag `<div class="blub">`, and another as the last widget with div end tag `</div>` :D

Comment: Blocks have been suggested in another source of info. If someone makes that an answer I'll accept it.